# calling function python file

Tags: python, file, function, file-io

I'm trying to call a function to parse a file after opening certain files from directory. Do i need to open the file in the function? Work with `if` statement but not when calling the function. New to Python could not make it work. Thank you and could not find answer in other question...

```
#!usr/bin/env/ python
import sys, re, os

#function to find the packetloss data in pcoip server files
def function_pcoip_packetloss(filename):
    lineContains = re.compile('.*Loss=.*')  #look for "Loss=" in the file
    for line in filename:
        if lineContains.match(line):    #check if line matches "Loss="
            print 'The file has: '  #prints if "Loss=" is found
            print line
            return 0;

#function to find the decrease in pcoip_server files
def function_pcoip_decrease(filename):
    lineContainsDecrease = re.compile('.*Decrease.*')
    for line in filename:
        if lineContainsDecrease.match(line):    #check if line matches "Decrease"
            print 'The file has: '          #prints if "Decrease is found"
            print line
            return 0;

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/pcoip-logs"):
    lineContainsServerFile = re.compile('.*server.*')

    for filename in files:
        if lineContainsServerFile.match(filename):
            filename = os.path.join(root,filename)
            with open(filename,'rb') as files:
                #lineContainsLoss = re.compile('.*Loss=.*')
                filename = os.path.join(root,filename)
                for line in files:
                    function_pcoip_packetloss(files);
                    function_pcoip_decrease(files);
              #works with these if but when I call the function does not work
                #for line in files:
                    #if lineContainsLoss.match(line):
                        #print line
```

Comment: What problem exactly are you having? Error message? Then post that (including the full traceback). You get no error but the results are not what you expect? Tell us what you got and what you expected. Help us help you.

Comment: @kindall no error msg, it does not seem to work when calling the function but works fine while using if statement as comment out in the code. What I wanted was to open certain file in directory, open numbers of files in a loop, parse it and print matching words/lines calling a function. let me know if you need more details. thank you

Comment: "It does not seem to work" is exactly the kind of thing I'm talking about. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the concept of file name and file handle. And using files inside the loop of files is not a good move. Try this:

```
    for filename in files:
            if lineContainsServerFile.match(filename):
                    filename = os.path.join(root,filename)
                    with open(filename,'rb') as filehandle:
                         function_pcoip_packetloss(filehandle)
                         filehandle.seek(0)
                         function_pcoip_decrease(filehandle)
```

Comment: This actually still won't work, because each of the functions being called iterate through `filehandle`. So `function_pcoip_decrease` will get the exhausted `filehandle` iterator, and not actually do any work.

Comment: True - i forgot that part only the first part will work - try combining the two functions & doo the checks on each line

Comment: thank you, works now. new bie sorry was a simple mistake. can you explain in brief about it filename and file handle and what would be a good move to solve it instead of using files inside the loop? @gkusner thank you

Comment: filename is the actual name of the file the file handle is a pointer to an open file object - also notice the rewind added to the code

Comment: wait I tried as you mentioned above and seems to pull out the matching word/line after parsing through the file. the first function works but second one does not, combining two function only works? or can I do it other way?

Comment: @gkusner Thanks a lot it helps me. appreciate your help I am learning new to this